# Converting a string to a datetime in MS SQL Server showing 19th Century date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

When I ran the below query in MS SQL Server 2019, it returned the correct date value:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'13/12/2019',103)
```

Output:

```
2019-12-13 00:00:00.000
```

But when I ran the below code block with the same query, I am not getting correct date value in the output. I am getting a 19th century date value.

```sql
DECLARE @BEFOREDATE varchar(30)

DECLARE @SqlStatment VARCHAR(1000)

BEGIN

   SET @BEFOREDATE = '13/12/2019'

   SET @SqlStatment = 'select CONVERT(DATETIME,' + @BEFOREDATE + ',103)'

   EXECUTE( @SqlStatment )

END
```

Output:

```
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

My SQL Server database has the below specifications:
[image]

Comment: Do `Select @SqlStatment;`.

Comment: Hint, you need quotes around the datetime constant. A parameterized query will avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is injection, and *bad* injection at that. The best way to debug "dynamic" SQL is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` the dynamic statement. If we do that, we get the following:

```sql
select CONVERT(DATETIME,01/03/2023,103)
```

So, this means you want to convert the **`integer`** expression `01/03/2023` to a `datetime`, so that's `1/3/2023`->`0/2023`->`0`, and `0` as a `datetime` is `1900-01-01`.

Coincidentally, if you used `date`, which it appears you should be using, you would have got a "better" error that would have likely pointed you to the *real* problem:

> Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.

As I stated though, the problem is injection, you should be **parametrising** the value. You can't do that with `EXEC(<Variable>)` syntax, and I actually stronly recommend against its use *because* of that; it promotes injection because it *can't* be parametrised. Instead use `sys.sp_executesql` and pass the variable to it as a parameter:

```sql
DECLARE @BeforeDate varchar(30);
DECLARE @SqlStatement nvarchar(MAX); --varchar is not a valid datatype for `sys.sp_exutesql`.

SET @BEFOREDATE = '01/03/2023';
SET @SqlStatement = 'SELECT CONVERT(datetime,@BeforeDate,103);';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SqlStatement, N'@BEFOREDATE varchar(30)', @BEFOREDATE;
```

Of course, this makes the whole "dynamic" statement pointless, as it's no longer dynamic.